# replace an object in an array without convert array to string javascript app script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm using app script to get information from API and use it as JSON.

```
var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(***);
var obj = JSON.parse(data); // To JSON
Logger.log(typeof(obj)); // return type as object
```

example of return array JSON:

```
var dataJson = [{age=20, gender=female, country=usa, name=sali, type=female},{age=25, gender=male, country=usa, name=john, type=female},{age=19, gender=female, country=usa, name=anita, type=female},{age=22, gender=male, country=usa, name=fredo, type=female}]
```

I want if gender = female change country to uk.
and if gender = male change country to canada.

I want after update array keep type as object not as string.

result as:

```
[{age=20, gender=female, country=uk, name=sali, type=female},{age=25, gender=male, country=canada, name=john, type=female},{age=19, gender=female, country=uk, name=anita, type=female},{age=22, gender=male, country=canada, name=fredo, type=female}]
```

note: the data in not fixed is changed dynamic.

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(data); // To JSON` this converts a JSON string to a javascript data structure.  It does not convert anything to JSON.

Comment: dataJson is not valid JSON.  It's also not a valid object either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply map over it

```js
var dataJson = [{age:20, gender:'female', country:'usa', name:'sali', type:'female'},{age:25, gender:'male', country:'usa', name:'john', type:'male'}]


const result = dataJson.map(({gender, ...rest}) => {
const isFemale = gender === 'female'
 return {
   ...rest,
   gender: isFemale? 'woman': 'man',
   country: isFemale ?'uk': 'canada'
 }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: but I want change gender if female to woman and if male to man?

Comment: @john you have asked another thing. I edited my answer

Comment: this can't work for my JSON the trike to remove Quote '' from  this line: const isFemale = gender === female. add femal without ''

Comment: what female object is?

Comment: I don't have any object or variable call female. It would throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply looking for:

```
dataJson = dataJson.map(elem => {
    if(elem.gender === 'female'){
        elem.country = 'uk'
    }
    if(elem.gender === 'male'){
        elem.country = 'canada'
    }
    return elem
})
```

Comment: this code is give object in multi array not in one array as original code